# Powershell storage cmdlets in 2012 r2

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

Can anyone help me with how to change the drive letter of a CDRom drive in Powershell 4?  I know it can be done with a GWMI call, but they have added a lot of storage related functionality in 4/2012 r2 and I am not able to figure out how it is done.

Documentation says Set-Partition is the way to go, but that only works for fixed drives.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specific to 2012 R2, but it should still work.

```
$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'e:'"
Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="X:"}
```

Comment: Yeah, it does.  I am going with this now, but I am just baffled that with all of the additions that they have made, this was overlooked.